# image disappears when trying to swap a class on ng-click and ng-class using angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I have a anchor tag which has an image using a CSS class when the page initally loads its grey and when the anchor is clicked, the image is a green one whihc changes based on css class search-open

With the below code, it works but Once the image class changes to green on a click  its not updated to green image till i move the mouse.  Any pointers. I am new to angular. any help will be appreciated.

```
  <a href ><span id="Icon" class="Search"  ng-click="activateSearch()"  ng-class="{'search-open':activeSearch}" custom-popover script="template"></span></a>
```

and within the controller  i have this ,

```
 $scope.activateSearch = function($event) {
        $scope.activeSearch = !$scope.activeSearch;
    }
```

while any click on the document can dismiss the popover and return the anchor to grey button image,

I do this ,

```
  $(document).on('click', function (e) {
            $('#Icon').each(function () {
                //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
                //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
                if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
                    $(this).popover('hide');
                    $scope.activeSearch = !$scope.activeSearch;
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: How is `$scope` even related to your document click event? How do you get $scope there?. And you cant duplicate id, id must be unique

Comment: I have placed the document click event in the same controller from where teh $scope is being triggered.  The id #Icon is unique. The above works , but only when i move teh mouse. till then it is blank. no image is applied.

Comment: I did not understand your issue, probably to hide popovers when you click outside? but one thing is you would need to do $scope.$apply() after scope update in documentclick event. See if that works

Answer (score 0):

You just need to force a scope digest cycle:

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
        $('#Icon').each(function () {
            //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
            //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
            if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
                $(this).popover('hide');
                $scope.activeSearch = !$scope.activeSearch;
                $scope.$apply();  // <--- this is the key
            }
        });
    });
```

I just don't understand why would you use both jQuery and Angular to set up click listeners on the same element.

---

Next thing:

```
$('#Icon').each
```

This makes no sense since IDs need to be unique, you can't/shouldn't have duplicates.

Comment: Cool, after adding a scope.apply()  it works correctly. I will remove the id , was just trying to get it working first. Yes, i agree this needs some refining. I was trying to get the solution to work first. pretty new to angular. thanks for your help shomz and  @PSL